# Add custom audiences to an Ad Group with Adwords API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using the python librairy for Adwords and I need to select the audiences that I want to link to a given ad group. I need to select audiences that are either remarketing and similar, custom intent or affinity.

How can I set the audiences when creating an ad group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some testing here is how to do it:

1. create the ad group and get its id
2. add the audience using `AdGroupCriterionService`

Here is my code for the 3 types of audiences I wanted to use (`self.client` is initiating `adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage`):

```
        ad_group_criterion_service = self.client.GetService('AdGroupCriterionService', version='v201809')
        audience_custom_affinity = {
            'xsi_type': 'BiddableAdGroupCriterion',
            'adGroupId': 'my_ad_group_id',
            'criterion': {
                'xsi_type': 'CriterionCustomAffinity',
                'type': 'CUSTOM_AFFINITY',
                'customAffinityId': 'my_audience_id'
            }
        }
        audience_custom_intent = {
            'xsi_type': 'BiddableAdGroupCriterion',
            'adGroupId': 'my_ad_group_id',
            'criterion': {
                'xsi_type': 'CriterionCustomIntent',
                'type': 'CUSTOM_INTENT',
                'customIntentId': 'my_audience_id'
            }
        }
        audience_remarketing = {
            'xsi_type': 'BiddableAdGroupCriterion',
            'adGroupId': 'my_ad_group_id',
            'criterion': {
                'xsi_type': 'CriterionUserList',
                'type': 'USER_LIST',
                'userListId': 'my_audience_id'
            }
        }
        operations = [
            {'operator': 'ADD',
                'operand': audience_custom_affinity},
            { 'operator': 'ADD',
                'operand': audience_custom_intent},
            {'operator': 'ADD',
            'operand': audience_remarketing}
        ]
        ad_group_criterion_service.mutate(operations)
```

Comment: In your example, how is the custom audience (`my_audience_id`) created? Where is `my_audience_id` coming from? Can you post an example? That would be much appreciated!

Comment: it's coming from the list of audiences I have in Adwords (Tools > Share library > Audience manager)

Comment: I see, so it wasn't created programmatically?

Comment: @roundrobin as far as I know, you can create client lists programatically through the Adwords API, but this code is just attaching a set of pre-created audiences/client lists to an ad group

Comment: Here you can find some Python examples or equivalent in other languages @roundrobin: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/remarketing#create-a-remarketing-user-list-audience. If you need anything else feel free to contact me, I use the API extensively every day